# Facebook Graph - Instagram Business ID: not always returned for the same page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm facing to a strange issue with Facebook Graph API: for a given Facebook Page, the API does not always retrieved the Instagram Business ID associated.

My client have his page "WonderfulClientPage" which he is owner and admin.
He invited me to be administrator of his page. So, both of our Facebook accounts have the MANAGE role.

When he trying to get his Instagram Business ID from the Graph API through our Facebook App, it does not working: the API replying without the ID. The API response:

```
{
   "id": "100[...]966"
}
```

But, when I'm doing the same with my account, it's working fine:

```
{
   "instagram_business_account": {
      "id": "178[...]519"
   },
   "id": "100[...]966"
}
```

When tried to do it with another account, freshly invited as an administrator: it's working !

It seems it's mandatory to be a "recent" administrator of a page to retrieved the Instagram Business ID ... It's look liker weird.

The HTTP request:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/100[...]966?access_token=EAAGqeRDgkT8BAF[...]WMc90asIcZD&fields=instagram_business_account
```

Data from Token Debug (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/):

```
Type: User
Valid: True
Origin: Web
Scopes: email, read_insights, pages_show_list, ads_management, business_management, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_insights, instagram_content_publish, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_posts, public_profile
```

Does someone had the same issue ? Is there something else I'm missing to explain that ?

Comment: When `pages_show_list` is granted via the login dialog, Facebook lets people decide _which_ of the pages the user is an admin of should be exposed via API. The page in question is probably not among them (can f.e. happen, if the user granted the permission to the app, before they became admin of the page.) Try and have them remove that permission (or all), and then ask for it again - and have them check if they get to chose the page in the login dialog then.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for your answer. 
It was something I suspected, I did a share-screen call with my client to ensure this point. The given page was selected in the Facebook grant pop-up dialog.